# No data in SQLite Editor

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have problem to insert data in a SQLite database. When I clicked button save, I didn't see the data in SQLite Editor..
What's wrong this code?

**1) AddMedicine.java**

```
private void AddData() {
    btn3.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                HashMap queryValues = new HashMap();
                queryValues.put("medicine", medicine.getText().toString());
                queryValues.put("quantity", quantity.getText().toString());
                queryValues.put("date", date.getText().toString());
                queryValues.put("time", time.getText().toString());
                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(queryValues);

                if (isInserted = true) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddMedicine.this, "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(AddMedicine.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    //   this.callHomeActivity(view);

                } else
                    Toast.makeText(AddMedicine.this, "Data not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

**2) DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public boolean insertData(String Name, String quantity, String Date, String Time) {

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, Name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, quantity);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, Date);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, Time);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well to start, with `if (isInserted = true)` isn't doing what you want. It should be `if (isInserted == true)` or more simply `if (isInserted)`. (Likewise your return statement later can just be `return result != -1;`. It's not wrong right now, but longer than it needs to be.) With that change, what toast do you get?

Comment: I'd also strongly advice you to avoid using raw types, and to follow Java naming conventions, and to avoid using strings for everything - and the `insertData` method you've shown us isn't the one you're calling.

Comment: I just seen this code if (isInserted = true)  ..Thank you for your remind. I should use db.query isn't? Not db.rawQuery right? What's you mean  insertData method isn't the one you're calling?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I should use db.query isn't?" - but you appear to be calling an overload of `insertData` which takes a single parameter, but you've *shown* us an overload with 4 parameters...

Answer (score 1):

Method `insertData` needs 4 parameters for work, but you pass `HashMap` as the only argument into this method. May be it is your problem?

Hope it helps.

**UPD**

You have several possibilities to change this situation. 
The first - use code, suggested by *GreenRobo*, or you can rewrite your method `insertData` to fit your `HashMap` argument. For example:

```
public boolean insertData(Map<String> map) { 
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();     
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
     contentValues.put(COL_2, map.get("name"));
     contentValues.put(COL_3, map.get("quantity"));
     contentValues.put(COL_4, map.get("date"));
     contentValues.put(COL_5, map.get("time")); 
     long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues); 
    return (result != - 1);
}
```

Comment: That's mean, I should create methos HashMap like this:                                         HashMap queryValues = new HashMap(String m, String q, String d, String t);

Comment: This should be a comment - if the OP's code is running at all (which it sounds like it is), then presumably there's an overload taking a map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

.

```
myDb.insertData(medicine.getText().toString(), quantity.getText().toString(), date.getText().toString(), time.getText().toString());
```

.
According to your method implementation

Answer (score 0):

1st you have to create a model class for your database to save and retrieve data from it.

```
public class User {
private int id;
private String medicine;
private String quantity;
private String date;
private String time;   

public User(String time, String medicine, String quantity, String date) {
    this.time = time;
    this.medicine = medicine;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.date = date;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getMedicine() {
    return medicine;
}

public void setMedicine(String medicine) {
    this.medicine = medicine;
}

public String getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}
```

}
 And your Adddata method will be like:

btn3.setOnClickListener(

```
new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String e1 = medicine.getText().toString();
            String e2 = quantity.getText().toString();
            String e3 = date.getText().toString();
            String e4 = time.getText().toString();

            User user = new User();
            user.setMedicine(e1);
            user.setQuantity(e2);
            user.setDate(e3);
            user.setTime(e4);



            Databasehandler db = new Databasehandler(getActivity());
            db.insert(user);

        }
    });
```

And replce your insertdata method in Databasehandler with :

```
boolean insertData(User user){
    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_2,user.getMedicine());
    cv.put(COL_3,user.getQuantity());
    cv.put(COL_4, user.getDate());
    cv.put(COL_5, user.getTime());
    /// from here you can check the data you getting
    System.out.println("Medicine-------------" + user.getMedicine());
    System.out.println("Quan-------------" + user.getMedicine());
    System.out.println("Date-------------" + user.getDate());
    System.out.println("Time-------------"+user.getTime());
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What makes you think the OP *has* to create a model class? That's one design approach, but not the only one - and I don't see how your answer explains what the OP currently sees.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet : it is the simplest way to understand the SQLite using model class, it helps to save and retrieve data at any point of time

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad idea - I'm just saying that your claim that "you have to" is inaccurate, and that this doesn't address the issue that the user is actually seeing at the moment. There's nothing in your answer which explains the current behaviour.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:: i got what you trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

For the approach you used...:
these are the changes you have to do:

```
new View.OnClickListener()    {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View view){
    String e1 = medicine.getText().toString();
    String e2 = quantity.getText().toString();
    String e3 = date.getText().toString();
    String e4 = time.getText().toString();
    HashMap queryValues = new HashMap();

    queryValues.put("medicine", e1);
    queryValues.put("quantity", e2);
    queryValues.put("date", e3);
    queryValues.put("time", e4);
    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(queryValues);

    if (isInserted == true)  {
        Toast.makeText(AddMedicine.this, "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(AddMedicine.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        //   this.callHomeActivity(view);

    } else
        Toast.makeText(AddMedicine.this, "Data not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}

public boolean insertData(HashMap h) {

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, h.get("medicine"));
    contentValues.put(COL_3, h.get("quantity"));
    contentValues.put(COL_4, h.get("date"));
    contentValues.put(COL_5, h.get("time"));
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Till now your method of getting data from hashmap is wrong. 
One more apporch can be you can directly pass the e1,e2,e3,e4 in the method and rest your insertData will remain unchanged.

Comment: Thank you..But, I have error at this part:  Should I declare COL_3, COL_4, COL_5?                                                                                    contentValues.put(COL_2, h.get("medicine"));
        contentValues.put(COL_3, h.get("quantity"));
        contentValues.put(COL_4, h.get("date"));
        contentValues.put(COL_5, h.get("time"));

Comment: Here's COL_1,COL_2 etc are the same field name in table created @  onCreate.. For more ..please post your Dbhandler class snapshot.